# Automatically Update Woocommerce Prices

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I am running on WordPress v4.9.8 using WooCommerce v3.4.2.

Recently I've made an Excel spreadsheet which collects competitor's prices for multiple products via query. My target is to follow these prices on my web site.
Spreadsheet works fine; I have my new prices.
The question is how can I update them on web site in an automated way?

Is there any way to edit link structure in WooCommerce so I can directly command server to specify which product-id shall be changed along with how much?
Should I format a proper csv file for WooCommerce and update prices that way?

Apologize for my lack of knowledge. Any advice is highly appreciated.
Thank you for your time in advance!

Comment: Use wp all import and cron

Answer (score 1):

You can do a cron job and use the default woocommerce csv import feature without installing more plugins as it may slow down your site.
You will have to convert your Excel file to a CSV file.

More info about Cron:
Cron is a technical term used for commands to run on scheduled time or at regular intervals. Most web servers use it to maintain the server and run scheduled tasks.

WordPress comes with its own cron system which allows it to perform scheduled tasks. For example, checking for updates, deleting old comments from trash, etc.